# When do these Amazon warrants expire?

Tags: investing

The expiration date is blank according to the source.

[image]

Here's the original source:

https://www.centralcharts.com/en/284-amazoncom/warrants

Thanks so much!

Comment: If these are warrants issued by Amazon and trading on US markets then you can find the prospectus details  by searching the Edgar database.  Or is this some option-like product issued by a non US based broker/web site, disguised as warrants?

Comment: @BobBaerker I really don't know, wish I did. It looks like the ones listed as "Issuer" Citibank DE and CommerzBank DE may be issued by the German branches of those banks. But then I wonder about the ones with no issuer listed. Perhaps those are sold by Amazon, as you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: -Even thought warrants are equivalent to a long term option, AFAIK, there are no put and call warrants in the US.  In the US, options trade on option exchanges and warrants trade on the stock exchanges.  They're two different securities.   So that leads me to suspect that these are some sort of European variation.  You might try to find out where these trade and then search the regulatory agency in that locale for details (the equivalent of the OCC in the USA).